# Convert weird date and time in filename to a datetime object to compare against?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this datetime string which is part of a filename:

```
2024-01-30_17h00min05s237ms.jpg
```

For a given date and time (for example: 1/15/24 3:50 PM), I'd like to be able to tell if this given datetime is within that filename datetime plus 20 minutes.

I'm not sure how to get that filename format converted to a datetime object so I can do the date comparison.

Answer (score 0):

the basic idea is to use several splits.

```
import datetime 

file_name = '2024-01-30_17h00min05s237ms.jpg'
date,time = file_name.split('.')[0].split('_')

year, month, day = date.split('-')

hour, rem = time.split('h')
minute,rem = rem.split('min')

#not sure if you need seconds as well but you would need a small trick as 's' is in second and in ms
sec,milli = split('ms')[0].split('s')

datetime.datetime(year = int(year),month=int(month),day=int(day),hour=int(hour),minute=int(minute))
```